# Displaying custom multiple pins shows wrong pins for locations

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotationview

This problem has been bugging me for a couple of weeks already!

I have a tab bar application. On one tab I am entering points, and on another tab, the points are displayed on a map. Pins should be different dependent on the types of points.

The problem that I face is that every time I switch from one tab to another, the pin images change from what they should be to other images. For example, if I have four points on the map, three displayed as a circle and one as a triangle, the triangle will be moving around from one point to another. Images seem to change quite randomly.

So, this is the code:

ViewController.m

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    // Select the type of map
    if (isMapSelected == NO) {
       self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
    }

    else {
       self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    }


    // Add region to the map (center and span)
    [self addRegion];

    // Removing old annotation
    [self.mapView removeAnnotations:mapLocations];

    // Initializing arrays for the annotations
    mapLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [self addAnnotation];
}


-(void) addAnnotation 
{

   CLLocationCoordinate2D mapLocation;
   IGAMapAnnotation *mapAnnotation;

   // Calculate how many points are included
   NSInteger numberOfPoints = [coordinatesTempArray count];

   // Annotations will be added only of the flight plan includes at least one point
   if (numberOfPoints > 0) 
   {
     // Trying to add coordinates from the array of coordinates
     for (NSInteger i=0; i < ([coordinatesTempArray count]); i++) {

        mapAnnotation = [[IGAMapAnnotation alloc]init];

        // Taking a point in the array and getting its coordinates
        self.mapCoordinates = [coordinatesTempArray objectAtIndex:i];

        // Getting a point in the array and getting its lattitude and longitude
        self.mapLatitude = [[self.mapCoordinates objectAtIndex:0]doubleValue];
        self.mapLongitude = [[self.mapCoordinates objectAtIndex:1]doubleValue];

        // Assigning the point coordinates to the coordinates to be displayed on the map
        mapLocation.latitude = self.mapLatitude;
        mapLocation.longitude = self.mapLongitude;

        // Adding coordinates and title to the map annotation
        mapAnnotation.coordinate = mapLocation;
        mapAnnotation.title = [navaidNamesTempArray objectAtIndex:i];
        mapAnnotation.subtitle = nil;
        mapAnnotation.navaidType = [navaidTypesTempArray objectAtIndex:i];

        // Adding the annotation to the array that will be added to the map
        [mapLocations addObject:mapAnnotation];
    }

    // Adding annotations to the map
    [self.mapView addAnnotations:mapLocations];
    }
 }


-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{

   if([annotation isKindOfClass:[IGAMapAnnotation class]]) 
   {
     IGAMapAnnotation *myLocation = (IGAMapAnnotation *) annotation;
     MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"IGAMapAnnotation"];

     if (annotationView == nil)
        annotationView = myLocation.annotationView;
     else
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
     return annotationView;
   }
   else
      return nil;
}
```

IGAMapAnnotation.m

```
@synthesize coordinate = _coordinate;
@synthesize title = _title;
@synthesize subtitle = _subtitle;
@synthesize type = _type;

// Tried to have this init method but was never able to make it work. Without it, the program crashes too!!!!

-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)newTitle Type:(NSString *)type Location:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) newCoordinate 
{
   self = [super init];

   if (self) {
       _title = newTitle;
       _coordinate = newCoordinate;
       _type = type;
   }

   return self;
}


-(MKAnnotationView *) annotationView {
   MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:self reuseIdentifier:@"IGAMapAnnotation"];
   annotationView.enabled = YES;
   annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
   annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

   if ([self.type isEqual: @"A"] || [self.type isEqual: @"B"] || [self.type isEqual: @"C"]) 
   {
     annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"circle.png"];
   }
   else if ([self.type isEqual: @"D"]) 
   {
     annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"triangle.png"];
   }
   else if ([self.type isEqual: @"E"]) 
   {
     annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"square.png"];
   }
   else 
   {
     annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oval.png"];
   }
   return annotationView;
}

@end
```

This is it. So far, the behaviour makes no sense to me.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: One note: moving this `[self.mapView removeAnnotations:mapLocations]` from viewWillAppear to addAnnotation solves the above problem but then the old annotation pins are not removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like an annotation view re-use issue.

When the annotations are re-displayed, they are re-using views with the images of previous annotations.  The `image` property in the view is not being updated as it should be when it is re-used for another annotation.

In the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method, this code looks wrong:

```
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeue...
if (annotationView == nil)
    annotationView = myLocation.annotationView;
else
    annotationView.annotation = annotation;
```

If the `dequeue` returns a view (ie. a previously-created view that may have been created for an annotation of a *different* type), its `annotation` property is updated but its `image` property is not updated.

The existing code only sets the `image` property when creating a new annotation view (when `dequeue` returns `nil`).

Right now, the annotation *view* creation and `image`-setting code is in the annotation *model* class `IGAMapAnnotation`.  It would be better to create a custom `MKAnnotationView` class that automatically updates the `image` property whenever its `annotation` property is updated.

However, another alternative is to put all the logic in the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method itself (and remove the `annotationView` method from the `IGAMapAnnotation` class).

Example of the updated `viewForAnnotation` delegate method:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if (! [annotation isKindOfClass:[IGAMapAnnotation class]])
    {
        //return default view if annotation is NOT of type IGAMapAnnotation...
        return nil;
    }


    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"IGAMapAnnotation"];

    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"IGAMapAnnotation"];
        //these properties don't change per annotation 
        //so they can be set only when creating a new view...
        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    }
    else
    {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }


    //whether we are using a completely new view or a re-used view,
    //set the view's image based on the current annotation...

    IGAMapAnnotation *myLocation = (IGAMapAnnotation *) annotation;
    if ([myLocation.type isEqual: @"A"] || [myLocation.type isEqual: @"B"] || [myLocation.type isEqual: @"C"])
    {
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"circle.png"];
    }
    else if ([myLocation.type isEqual: @"D"])
    {
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"triangle.png"];
    }
    else if ([myLocation.type isEqual: @"E"])
    {
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"square.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oval.png"];
    }


    return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: Anna. I used your alternative method and looks like it is working properly. MANY MANY THANKS!!!