# annotations for iOS MapView showing incorrect icon images

Tags: ios, uiimageview, mkmapview, mkannotation

In my iOS app I have a MapView and I have a custom Annotation (extends MKAnnotation).

I set an icon image for each annotation depending on it's type. When I first load up the map view, all the images are correct, but as you move the view around the images start to change to different ones.

It's almost like the OS is recycling annotations and bringing them back as they reappear on the screen, but with the wrong image.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks for your help.

Here is my delegate method:

```
    -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomAnnotationView class]]) {
        CustomAnnotationView *customAnnotation = (CustomAnnotationView *)annotation;
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CustomAnnotation"];
        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = customAnnotation.annotationView;
        }
        else{
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        return annotationView;
    }
    else{
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Here is what my object looks like:

```
@interface CustomAnnotationView : NSObject<MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic,readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *subtitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) Thing *thing;

-(id)init:(Thing *)thing;
-(MKAnnotationView *) annotationView;
-(void)setDistance:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)point;
@end
```

Comment: Can you add some code for how you're setting your annotation views?

Comment: Most likely improper handling of annotation view re-use.  Posting at least your viewForAnnotation delegate method code would allow someone to give a specific answer.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232668/displaying-custom-multiple-pins-shows-wrong-pins-for-locations for one example.

Comment: Currently, the only place the annotation view's image is set is in the annotationView method of the CustomAnnotationView class, right?

Comment: @Anna that's correct

Comment: That means in viewForAnnotation, when the view's annotation is updated (when a view is being re-used), the view's image (and any other related stuff like "thing", "distance", etc) needs to be updated to match the new annotation.  Look at the linked answer.  Your issue is similar in that the annotation _model_ object is doubling as the _view_ or at least the view-creator.

Comment: This creates confusion with view re-use because now annotation X is responsible for creating a view for annotation Y.  It's cleaner to keep the annotation model class (the one that implements MKAnnotation) separate from the view class (the one that subclasses MKAnnotationView).